# SQLAlchemy changes precision of floating-point number when updating a Postgres entry

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, precision

I use SQLAlchemy with an Object Relational Mapper to access a Postgres database. Everything is working fine except that SQLAlchemy changes the precision of some (but not all) floating-point numbers when I do an upgrade of a database entry.

Let's say my database has a table `My_table` that looks like this:

```
id  |  my_float
----------------
1   | [NULL]
2   |  1.11
3   |  1.12
```

I fetch the entry with id=1 and update it:

```
from dbconnection import dbsession
from models import My_table
my_instance = dbsession.query(My_table).filter_by(id=1).first()
my_instance.my_float = 0.15
dbsession.commit()
```

The result in my Postgres Database looks like this:

```
select * from my_table where id=1;
id  |  my_float
----------------
1   | 0.15000001
```

Is there a way to make SQLAlchemy write the exact number to Postgres?
**Edit**: I should add that the column `my_float` is of type `FLOAT(2)`.

Comment: No. It has nothing in particular to do  with SQLAlchemy, but that computers operate in binary. The is vast majority of fractional point values in decimal (base 10) representation **cannot be represented exactly** in binary representation (base 2).  All floating point values are basically estimates. However, you may be able to specify the required number of decimal digits. I, however, do not know how to do that in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @Belayer That's perfect. Would you mind posting it as an answer so that I can mark the question solved? My mistake was that I had defined the column 'my_float' as FLOAT(2) believing that this would give me a floating-point number of two digits. But this gives a single-precision floating point number: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html. Creating the table again with 'myfloat' as NUMERIC(4,2) gave me the range that I need (from 0.00 to 99.99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It has nothing in particular to do with SQLAlchemy, but that computers operate in binary. The is vast majority of fractional point values in decimal (base 10) representation cannot be represented exactly in binary representation (base 2). All floating point values are basically estimates. However, you may be able to specify the required number of decimal digits. I, however, do not know how to do that in SQLAlchemy.